# Const qualifier ignored

Tags: c, constants, typedef, c99

I have a struct type_s. Then I typedef a pointer to a struct type_s as type.

If I have a `const struct type_s*` then the compiler will correctly complain if an assignment is made to the struct member, as seen in function Test1(). But if I make a const type, which is a typedef for the same struct pointer the compiler will not complain and compile, function Test2().

```
typedef struct type_s* type ;
struct type_s
{
    int a ;
} ;

void Test1( const struct type_s* t )
{
    t->a = 123 ;  //complains, ok
}

void Test2( const type t )
{
    t->a = 123 ;   //doesn't, it should in my oppinion
}
```

To me they are logically both the same thing. What am I missing?

Is the only solution to create another typedef for a constant pointer to that struct like this:

`typedef const struct type_s* ctype ;`

which will work correctly as in Test1().

Comment: If you have `const T t`, that means that `t` is the thing that's const.  `typedef`s are not the same as `#define`s.

Comment: Once you defined the type (with the `typedef`) you can't change that type any further. Any qualifiers apparently applied to the type, apply instead to the object. The `const` in question is not ignored; it is applied to the object `t`. Inside the function you can't do `t = NULL;`

Comment: `const type t` means `struct s_type * const t`. Yet another reason not to use pointer typedefs.

Comment: [C99 in HTML](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html)

Comment: @MattMcNabb I have the same opinion, but then I read a lot of c libraries where that is done constantly to hide the struct.

Comment: There's lots of bad code out there

Comment: @MattMcNabb I guess making someone write that extra `*` isn't so bad :), + you know what the type really is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're missing is that a const pointer is not the same thing as a pointer to a const object.  You have one of each.  A const pointer is a pointer whose stored address is not modifiable; a pointer to const is one which cannot be used to modify its referent.

Comment: Where do I have a *const pointer*?

Comment: `const type` is equivalent to `type const` which in your case gives you `struct type_s* const` whereas you thought you were getting `const struct type_s*`.  Another way to look at it is that you wanted `(const struct type_s)*` but you got `const (struct type_s*)`.

Answer (score 1):

They are not the same thing. `const` has different semantics when applied to the  definition or declaration of a pointer variable and a non-pointer variable.

```
const struct type_s *t
```

The above statement defines `t` to be a pointer to an object of type `const struct type_s`. Here, `const` qualifies the type `struct type_s` of the object `t` points to, not the pointer `t`.

```
typedef struct type_s *type ;
```

The above statement defines an alias named `type` for the type `struct type_s *`.

```
const type t;
// equivalent to
type const t;
// equivalent to
struct type_s *const t;
```

The above statement defines `t` to be a constant object of type `type`. Here `const` qualifies the object. You cannot replace the `typedef` with its original type and reinterpret it as if it were a macro. The pointer information is embedded in the `typedef` and it will be treated as a non-pointer type.